# What are valid places to put HTML comments?

Tags: html

I am only concerned about HTML5 in this question.

This does not seem to work:

```
<code><<!-- test -->span class="otherCode">Bar</span></code>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/dYSeK/ )

However, this works for me when I have long URLs that I want to wrap in source code.

```
<div>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=test">https://<!--
    -->www.google.co.in/search?q=test</a>
</div>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/wMGdk/ )

What are all the valid places in an HTML code where I can place HTML comments?

Comment: Re *"does not seem to work"*: In what way does it not work? Does not pass HTML validation? Unexpected content of the rendered web page in a web browser? An IDE or a build step that complains? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen See the two jsfiddle links. In the first one, the `span` tag is not an HTML element. It appears as text "<span" in the output. In the second link, there is no such problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place comments between any tag, but not inside of a tag declaration.

So, this is correct:

```
<code><!-- test --><span class="otherCode">Bar</span></code>
```

...and here's what it looks like properly indented (which is why it makes sense):

```
<code>
    <!-- test -->
    <span class="otherCode">Bar</span>
</code>
```

Answer (score -7):

You can place comments on the header and body section.

In your example try this:

```
<code><!-- test -->span class="otherCode">Bar</span></code
```

I just removed a less than sign.

Comment: This obviously just breaks the `<span>` tag.